# how to use diff command line to compare the newest file (last modified)

Tags: batch-file, command, compare, diff

I have written a bat file in windows which compares 2 files and lists all the difference (code below). Currently it only compares files with the name 1.txt to 2.txt and outputs the differences to 786.txt.

I want it to compare the newest file (last modified) against 2.txt and output the result to 786.txt.

Please can someone help. The code so far is below:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (
  'diff c:\1.txt c:\2.txt ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
) do @echo %%b >>c:\786.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the latest file:

```
 cd /d c:\
 for /f %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d /tw') do (set latest=%%a & goto :eof)
```

Then you would just use %latest% in place of 1.txt

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. I'm a complete novice at this. Can you please show me how I'd put both sets of code together so the bat file will execute.

Comment: first the code from this answer, followed by your code (use `%latest%` in place of `1.txt`)

Comment: I have added the code into a bat file, but when I run it nothing happens. The code looks like this:                                  cd /d c:\
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d /tw') do (set latest=%%a & goto :eof)
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (
  'diff c:\%latest% c:\2.txt ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
) do @echo %%b >>c:\786.txt

Comment: Everything looks right. When you say nothing happens, do you mean the 786.txt file isn't created? echo out %latest% and see what it is. Make sure it's the file you're expecting.